# Data submission via PHP server-side

Tags: php, html, client-server, sql-update

I am baffled why the form won't send and then be redirected to index.php page. I'm very new to PHP and trying to use the User object. Here's what I have so far.

```
<main>
        <header>
            <h1>Create New Account</h1>
        </header>            

        <section id="formEntry">
            <form id="createacct" name="createacct" action="CreateAccount.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Enter your information</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fieldName">First Name</td>
                            <td class="inputField"><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" form="createacct" size="30" maxlength="50" onchange="firstNameUpdated()"></td>                                
                            <td id="firstnamemsg"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fieldName">Last Name</td>
                            <td class="inputField"><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" form="createacct" size="30" maxlength="50" onchange="lastNameUpdated()"></td>
                            <td id="lastnamemsg"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fieldName">Email</td>
                            <td class="inputField"><input type="email" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" form="createacct" size="30" maxlength="50" onchange="emailUpdated()"></td>
                            <td id="emailmsg"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fieldName">Select a username</td>
                            <td class="inputField"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" form="createacct" size="30" maxlength="50" onchange="usernameUpdated()"></td>
                            <td id="usernamemsg"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fieldName">Enter your password</td>
                            <td class="inputField"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" form="createacct" size="30" maxlength="50" onchange="pwdUpdated()"></td>
                            <td id="passwordmsg"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="fieldName">Confirm password</td>
                            <td class="inputField"><input type="password" id="confirmpwd" name="confirmpwd" form="createacct" size="30" maxlength="50" onchange="confirmUpdated()"></td>
                            <td id="confirmpwdmsg"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="saveMsg"></td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="submitButton">                                    
                                <input type="reset" value="Clear all fields" class="styleButton" onclick="clearFields(this)">
                                <input type="submit" value="Create New Account" class="styleButton" onclick="return createNewAccount()">                                    
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                        
                </fieldset>
            </form>                
        </section> 

        <?php 
            include 'CreateAccount.php';

            $user = new User();

            $user->first = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
            $user->last = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
            $user->emailaddress = trim($_POST["emailAddress"]);
            $user->username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            $user->password = trim($_POST["password"]);
            $user->confirmpwd = trim($_POST["confirmpwd"]);

            $isValid = $user->validate();
        ?>

    </main>
```

And the PHP File (CreateAccount.php):

```
<?php

Class User {
    public $first;
    public $last;
    public $emailaddress;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $confirmpwd;

    // validation function 
    function validate() {
        if (($this->first != null || $this->first != '') &&
                ($this->last != null || $this->last != '') &&
                ($this->emailaddress != null || $this->emailaddress != '') &&
                ($this->username != null || $this->username != '') &&
                ($this->password != null || $this->password != '') &&
                ($this->confirmpwd != null || $this->confirmpwd != '') && 
                ($this->password === $this->confirmpwd)) {
            storeData($this->first, $this->last, $this->emailaddress, $this->username, $this->password);
            header('Location: TestPage.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: CreateNewAccount.php');
        }
    }

}        

exit()
```

?>

What am I doing wrong here? Every time I submit, it redirects me to CreateAccount.php and comes out blank. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: what does `storeData()` do and where's the function for it?

Comment: remove the exit() please and try again, because you are exiting after creating an User Object, validate() will never be reached and page will be blank.

Comment: facepalming myself. yeah, that exit will do it here. Your script's exiting without processing anything

Comment: You are posting data to CreateAccount.php which only has a class definition and nothing else. No functions are called, what do you expect to happen? Maybe you want to change your form's action to "" so it posts to current page where you actually use User class?

Comment: storeData() is a function that will persist the data ignore that part for now.

Comment: I removed the exit() but didn't do the trick. After removing, it displayed the list of errors which was unexpected. Here's what I have, the first line,   Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\HearingDogTrainingLog\CreateNewAccount.php on line 81

Comment: @Marc I revisited the question to check on its status and what you wrote ^ that I knew and which is why I posted the error reporting link. All you needed to do was to use a conditional statement around your code, with a named submit button; problem solved. I don't see the reason for a rewrite as you posted in an answer below. The `exit()` however, needed to be removed, regardless. *"After removing, it displayed the list of errors which was unexpected."* - It was expected.

Comment: The conditional statement I told you about, would have been like this: `$user = new User();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $user->first = trim($_POST["firstname"]); // rest of code... down to $isValid = $user->validate();
}`, done like dinner. @Marc and `<input type="submit" value="Create New Account" class="styleButton" name="submit">`. Both of my comments should be posted as the real solution here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this to work. I was doing it all wrong, indeed, I spent hours figuring out to resolve the errors and moving the code around.

It turned out that I didn't need the PHP code in PHP web page, it was because I did not have a class object. Here's what I did - code snippet:

```
<?php

class User {
    public $first = '';
    public $last = '';
    public $emailaddress = '';
    public $username = '';
    public $password = '';
    public $confirmpwd = '';

    function validate() {
        if ($this->first === null || $this->first === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->last === null || $this->first === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->emailaddress === null || $this->emailaddress === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username === null || $this->username === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password === null || $this->password === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->confirmpwd === null || $this->confirmpwd === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $this->confirmpwd) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then back to my original code snippet above (CreateAccount.php), I changed the code to what it looks like now:

```
<?php

include 'User.php';

$user = new User();

$user->first = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
$user->last = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
$user->emailaddress = trim($_POST["emailAddress"]);
$user->username = trim($_POST["username"]);
$user->password = trim($_POST["password"]);
$user->confirmpwd = trim($_POST["confirmpwd"]);

$isValid = $user->validate();

if ($isValid) {
    storeData($first, $last, $emailaddress, $username, $password); //ignore the line 
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    header('Location: CreateNewAccount.php');
}

?>
```

Note that I moved the variables from PHP web page to PHP file (CreateAccount.php), problem solved and not getting the Undefined index error throwing at me.

Regarding exit() I used in original code, it works either with or without exit() even though it's not necessary but for convenience purposes.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

# In your CreateAccount.php,
# update your code like this

Class User {
    public $first;
    public $last;
    public $emailaddress;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $confirmpwd;

    // validation function
    function validate() {
        if (($this->first != null || $this->first != '') &&
            ($this->last != null || $this->last != '') &&
            ($this->emailaddress != null || $this->emailaddress != '') &&
            ($this->username != null || $this->username != '') &&
            ($this->password != null || $this->password != '') &&
            ($this->confirmpwd != null || $this->confirmpwd != '') &&
            ($this->password === $this->confirmpwd)) {
            storeData($this->first, $this->last, $this->emailaddress, $this->username, $this->password);
            header('Location: TestPage.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: CreateNewAccount.php');
        }
    }

}

#notice that the exit code is been removed and hopefully this should work..
```

Comment: When you copy and paste the OP code you have to add the explanation of what you have changed and why this will solve the issue. Also it will be handy if you also read the answers and comments other have posted.

Comment: Yeah sure, but my PHPSTORM IDE tests code typically before i post it here, So FYI the answer is yes i have tested it and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE and removing the exit() like I said above didn't do the trick. It just displayed the list of errors.